# A loop to add data to certains cells with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am new with pandas and I can't quite figure out what went wrong.

I have two dataframes: first one is item.csv and has columns "item id", "rate_M", "num_M", "rate_F", and "num_F" / second one is data.csv and has columns "user id", "item id", "rating" and "gender".
[image: sample picture of item.csv]
[image: sample picture of data.csv]

With these two dataframes I would like to make a loop so that as it goes through the rows in data.csv,

1. it adds the value from "rating" column to the item.csv, with row of the same "item id" and columns "rate_M" or "rate_F" according to "gender" column
2. it adds 1 to the item.csv, with row of same "item id" and "num_M" or "num_F" according to "gender" column

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
item = pd.read_csv("item.csv")

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    if row["gender"] == 'M':
        item.at[row["item id"], "rate_M"] += row["rating"]
        item.at[row["item id"], "num_M"] += 1
    if row["gender"] == 'F':
        item.at[row["item id"], "rate_F"] += row["rating"]
        item.at[row["item id"], "num_F"] += 1
        
item.to_csv("item2.csv", index=False)
```

However, when I run this with command prompt, it returns **ValueError: 1682 is not in range**.
[image: error]
Could anyone tell me where it went wrong and how I could code so that it actually performs what I want it to do?

Comment: please provide line number of the error and please provide data files if possible

Comment: Please share sample input data frames for both `data.csv` and `item.csv` and the expected output based on that. This would make it clear to the rest of us.

Comment: @AajKaal I have added the error and files to make it clear. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: item id from data.csv is the index in item.csv? if not set it as index before using at[row]...